# Does membrane permeability affect the equilibrium reached by two different concentrations of equally charged ions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, biophysics, diffusion, electrochemistry, ions

I'm asking this question to aid understanding of the formation of membrane potential in a cell from electrochemical gradients of ions e.g. why the membrane potential is skewed towards the equilibrium potential of K+ instead of somewhere middle between Na+ and K+ (textbooks tell you that it's because of the higher membrane permeability to K+)

Suppose I do an experiment with two chambers, denoted by A and B. The two chambers are separated by an artificial selectively permeable membrane which has a 50x greater permeability for K+ than for Na+ (similar to a cell membrane). Only passive diffusion occurs at the membrane, meaning there are no sodium-potassium pumps or other stuff at the membrane.

Chamber A contains 140mM of Na+ and 5mM of K+ while chamber B contains 5mM of Na+ and 140mM K+

What would happen if the experiment is left on its own with enough time for it to reach equilibrium?

**My thoughts**

I believe at equilibrium, there will be equal concentrations of ions on chamber A and B. My reasoning is that,

Assuming I pause at an instance of ions exchange where there is a net 100 K+ diffusing from A to B and a net 2 Na+ diffusing from B to A.

After that, chamber A becomes more negative than chamber B, creating an electric force that attracts both K+ (the ones travelled to B) and Na+ in B.

This negative electric force coupled with Na+ concentration gradient causes Na+ to increase its net diffusion to chamber A. While the negative electric force (now slightly reduced by the increase net diffusion of Na+) fighting against the K+ concentration gradient reduces the net movement of K+ to chamber B.

With more cycles of exchange, the above scenario repeats itself and every time the K+ leaves chamber A making A more positive, increase net Na+ from B comes into A to neutralise the positive charge. This neutralisation, particularly from Na+, allows a small net K+ to leave A and enter B.

At equilibrium, concentrations of K+ and Na+ will be equal in both membranes as there will be no electric or chemical gradient.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you think permeability should influence equilibrium values?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevant, but how large are the chambers?

Comment: @BioPhysicist i have edited my response to add my reasoning. It's hard to voice how I think permeability should influence permeability value but I'll try my best.

I suppose the 50:1 permeability COULD influence equilibrium value by, allowing K+ diffused to chamber B to return back to chamber A quicker than Na+ to neutralise the positive charge. Meaning there isn't that net increase of Na+ moving from B to A.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Therefore at equilibrium, K+ and Na+ in both chambers form their own electrochemical gradient such that there isn't a net movement of each ion despite there being a difference in Na+/K+ concentrations across both chambers

Comment: @BioPhysicist Btw technically this isn't for homework and exercise, it's an example given by my teacher to apparently illustrate the impact of membrane permeability on the generation of membrane potential across two areas where there are different concentrations of ions. I have edited the intro to my question to be more explicit in how it can be applied to the membrane potential concept.

Comment: @BøbbyLeung The tag applies to more than just questions that have been assigned explicitly as homework